# Execute script on login Fedora 21

Tags: linux, bash, script, fedora, fedora-21

I'm trying to launch a script located in my home directory when I login on Fedora 21. I have tried to make this desktop file in `/usr/share/autostart`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Wallpapers
Exec=/home/user/Wallpaper-script/launch.sh
Comment=Autostart wallpaper download and slideshow
Terminal=false
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
```

When I reboot or login, the script doesn't launch; however, when I manually open the file, the script launches fine. What am I doing wrong here?

I can supply the script files if necessary.

Comment: How do you execute the script manually? Moreover is the script executable `chmod u+x /home..../launch.sh ` and has it inside the as first line `#!/bin/bash` or analogue [_Shebang_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)?

Comment: I manually start the script either by finding the desktop file and opening it in nautilus or by running `/home/user/Wallpaper-script/launch.sh` in the terminal. Both the desktop file and the script are executable and the script has `#!/bin/sh` in the first line

Comment: Just a try: try to add a couple of `date >> /tmp/launch.templog.log` at the beginning and at the end of your script in order to check if it is executed and if it runs till the end.

Comment: If I add that to the beginning and end of my script the file in `/tmp/` does not get created. If I launch the script manually though, it does.

Comment: Ok one steps forward: it is not executed at all. Can you check if the file in `/usr/share/autostart/` is named `as_you_want.desktop` and owned by `root:root`?  Silly question, but I've to do, is your environment GNOME?

Comment: The file is correctly named and I ran  `sudo chown root:root /usr/share/autostart/wallpapers.desktop` so root owns it but to no avail. Yes my environment is GNOME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out. Just had to put the desktop file in `~/.config/autostart` and then it worked like a charm. Thank you so much for the help though Hastur. If anyone is interested in the script, an installation one is available here [Link](https://ninjan.co/files/install.sh)

Comment: You're weicome. BTW there are many folder in which you can find files that start automatically. Give a look on google or [just to have an idea here](http://blog.davidedmundson.co.uk/node/8).