# Automating task

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, bash-scripting, systemd

I need to run that command at the boot: `xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'`. So I write a script called swapkeys.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'
```

And I make it executable with:

$`chmod +x swapkeys.sh`

Then I write my Unit called swapkey.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Swapping keys from Esc >> Ctrl

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/local/swapkeys.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I run: $`systemctl enable swapkey.service` after what I do: $`systemctl start swapkey.service`. Then I check status of Unit: $`systemctl -l status swapkey.service` and get this error:

[image: error report from systemctl]

And I have a question, what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem is solved thanks to grawity. I made a file called swapkey.desktop in `~/.config/autostart` which contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Swapkey
Exec=/home/vitaly/.config/autostart-scripts/swapkey.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

Also I write a shell script that I placed, as you can see above, in folder that I create by myself. The script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'
```

And, I don't know was it necessary or not, I made it executable with `chmod +x ...`. And voilà it's working as expected. P.S. System on which I work - Manjaro linux

Comment: The file in `Exec=` needs to be executable (and with a #! header). The .desktop file doesn't need to be executable (although it _may_ have +x and `#!/usr/bin/env dex`, but it's not necessary at all).

Comment: Why not writing `xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'` directly in the `Exec=` line, though?

Answer (score 3):

> what do I do wrong?

You're trying to do this from a service. Don't try to do X11-related stuff from a service.

---

Well, the first problem here is that your service wants to adjust parameters in Xorg, the X11 server... but it didn't tell systemd to actually *wait* until Xorg is ready and available. If the unit doesn't explicitly list an ordering (Before=, After=, etc), it will be started *in parallel* with everything else in the stage, and that quite often means it'll run much too early.

Unfortunately, in the case of Xorg, there *isn't* any unit you can order against. Although Xorg is started by a "display manager" such as GDM or LightDM, you won't often get far with "After=lightdm.service" because that just means "after the display manager itself is ready" – it doesn't mean "the display manager has started its first display". So your unit might still run early.

The second problem is that your program isn't told *which* Xorg to connect to. There actually is no such thing as "the" X11 server or "default" X11 server; it has to be specified explicitly via the $DISPLAY environment variable. Your desktop apps automatically know it – services don't. (One reason is that there could very easily be *multiple* Xorg instances, e.g. one for every logged in user.)

So that means your script needs to guess the display number somehow, and put it in $DISPLAY. Often it'll be numbered `:0`, but that's no guarantee.

The third problem is that even once the display manager starts its first display and your script successfully finds it, that isn't actually *your* display yet. That's just the *login screen* display. After you log in, it'll be thrown away (or hidden) and a fresh one started for your own desktop – so nothing that your *xcape* script did will carry over anyway.

---

The correct approach is to start such tools not *on boot,* but on *login,* and have them be started by your desktop itself (the session manager). Almost always, one of the following methods will be available:

- a .desktop file inside ~/.config/autostart/;
- a line in the ~/.xprofile shell script (create if non-existent);
- a line in the ~/.profile shell script (inside an "if [ "$DISPLAY" ]" check);

Comment: Ok, I create a ~/.xprofile where I put my code `#!/bin/sh/
  xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'` and make it executable with `chmod +x ...` and nothing happened. Maybe I miss some action?

Comment: It depends on what display manager and/or desktop environment you use. Some display managers read ~/.xprofile (it doesn't even need +x), others don't. You should try the .config/autostart method as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/898179/execute-script-on-login-fedora-21) or [here](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart).